# Finding field name in MongoDB nested data

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, nosql, pymongo

Is it possible to find the 'field name' using a regex first and then use that field name to find its value across all documents?

For example, if I have the following structure:

```
item : Object
  - quantity: 50
  - size: Object
    - h: 20
```

Ideally, if I want the value of h, I would query item.quantity.size.h ("field.nestedField"). However, I only know the name 'h' but not what it is nested under. Is it possible to retrieve the entire field name (item.quantity.size.h) and its value (20)? I would then like to use that field name to obtain the value from all other documents.

Comment: Please provide example data. Is a level an object or an array?

Comment: @Sassy your newly added sample data is still not clear about its structure. It would be the best if you can provide valid json documents.

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by: [MongoDB javascript `"$function"` not returning expected value in mongoplayground.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71638088/mongodb-javascript-function-not-returning-expected-value-in-mongoplayground/71650522#71650522)

You can use a `$function` aggregation, like this:

```
    db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      data: "$$ROOT"
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "flattenKeys": {
        "$function": {
          "body": "function flatten(dataList, keysToHandle){while(keysToHandle.length){origKeyData = keysToHandle.shift();for (const newKey of Object.keys(origKeyData.objData)){keysToHandle.push({objData:origKeyData.objData[newKey],keyData:`${origKeyData.keyData}.${newKey}`});dataList.push(`${origKeyData.keyData}.${newKey}`);}}return dataList}",
          "args": [
            [],
            [
              {
                objData: "$data",
                keyData: "data"
              }
            ]
          ],
          "lang": "js"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      matchingKeys: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$flattenKeys",
          as: "item",
          cond: {
            $regexMatch: {
              input: "$$item",
              regex: "keyD"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

See how it works [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/MVOWap_nw1S)

Comment: Does not work in pymongo

Comment: it gives an Out of memory OperationFailure even after adding allowDiskUse=True