# MongoDB - get subdocuments from arbitrary depth and object structure

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a collection that has objects of various random structures/depths. Within them, there is one object that I want to get as my results, which has a specific key/value pair that I can use to find them.

An example from my collection:

```json
{
    "_id": ObjectId("123"),
    "someKey": "blue",
    "children": [
        {
            "foo": "bar",
            "anotherKey": "anotherValue",
            "whateverA": 111
        }
    ]
}
{
    "_id": ObjectId("456"),
    "blahKey": "dog",
    "children": [
        {
            "anotherRandom": "randomValue",
            "children": [
                {
                    "moreRandom": "stuffValue",
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "foo": "bar",
                            "animalKey": "legsValue",
                            "whateverB": 222
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I would like to search for subdocuments that contain "foo: bar", and get a result that looks like the following:

```json
{
    "foo": "bar",
    "anotherKey": "anotherValue",
    "whateverA": 111
}
{
    "foo": "bar",
    "animalKey": "legsValue",
    "whateverB": 222
}
```

Then I can paginate the results. Is this even possible in MongoDB 5?

Thank you.

Comment: Please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71638088/mongodb-javascript-function-not-returning-expected-value-in-mongoplayground/71650522#71650522)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we use the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71638088/mongodb-javascript-function-not-returning-expected-value-in-mongoplayground/71650522#71650522) of @rickhg12hs

You can do something like:

**EDIT**: fixed to handle case of not found (Thanks to a comment by @Jimba):

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      res: {
        $function: {
                 body: "function drill(t, n) {if (n && n.length > 0){for (let elem of n){if(elem['foo'] && elem['foo'] === 'bar'){t.push(elem);}else {drill(t, elem.children)}}}return t}",
          args: [
            [],
            "$children"
          ],
          lang: "js"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      res: {
        $cond: [
          {$gt: [{$size: "$res"}, 0]},
          {$arrayElemAt: ["$res", 0]},
          {res: null}
        ]
      },
      _id: 0
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {res: {$ne: null}}
  },
  {
    $replaceRoot: {newRoot: "$res"}
  }
])
```

As you can see [on this playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/uEyKd0c3Exb).

We can use `$function` to recursively look for this key named `foo` and return the object that contains it.

**Edit** according to a question in the comment:

You can use your code to manipulate it according to your needs:
for example in js:

```
const key = 'foo';
const val = 'bar';
const body = `function drill(t, n) {if (n && n.length > 0){for (let elem of n){if(elem[${key}] && elem[${key}] === ${val}){t.push(elem);}else {drill(t, elem.children)}}}return t}`;


db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {res: {$function: {body, args: [[], "$children"], lang: "js"}}}
  },
  {
    $project: {
      res: {
        $cond: [
          {$gt: [{$size: "$res"}, 0]},
          {$arrayElemAt: ["$res", 0]},
          {res: null}
        ]
      },
      _id: 0
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {res: {$ne: null}}
  },
  {
    $replaceRoot: {newRoot: "$res"}
  }
])
```

Comment: I have one quick question regarding the above code:

- How do I incorporate my `db.collection.find( { ... } )` search parameters in the above aggragate command?

Thank you.

Comment: Your query is a `json` up until it is executed. You can edit this `json` in your code, according to your needs before you execute the query.

Comment: Updated the answer to contain this.

Comment: WARNING: the above javascript function (drill) does not work when the key is not found. It produces the following error:
`'newRoot' expression must evaluate to an object, but resulting value was: MISSING. Type of resulting value: 'missing'`,

Playground example: https://mongoplayground.net/p/jix1_LjIXv5

Comment: Updated the answer accordingly

Comment: Thank you for the update. Now it produces a lot of:
```
  {
    "res": {
      "res": null
    }
  }
```
Is there a way to completely remove empty/null subdocuments, so they are not counted in the pagination as results?

Comment: I think I got it. I needed to change the above `$cond` else condition from `{res:null}` to just null, and add a `{$match: { "res": { $ne: null } }} ` to remove null elements from the results.

Comment: Updated accordingly. Thanks